# How to make a byte array with an image from solution. (Windows Phone 8.1 runtime)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, arrays

I need to make a byte[] from an image, but first I think I have to save it as an image file like StorageFile or something, and pass it to this method, which will do the job:

```
private async Task<byte[]> StorageFileToByteArray(StorageFile file)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];

        if (null != file)
        {
            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

            var reader = new DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);

            byteArray = new byte[fileStream.Size];
        }

        return byteArray;
    }
```

But how to save it to StorageFile?

[image: This is my file]

This is how I load it in a BitmapImage:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/no_capture_receipt.png", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Then how to save this image in a StorageFile

Comment: Why do you want to use `BitmapImage` class?

Comment: I don't know. What do I need actually to perform this task?

Comment: You can use your image directly as a `StorageFile` without using the `BitmapImage` class. Will that work for you?

Comment: Are you going to work on the image data (pixels) or on the file content?

Comment: If you want to work with pixel data, I would recommend you to check this video (in french sorry, but the code is more important). Theimage session starts after 15min.
https://techdays.microsoft.fr/programmes/2015/fiche-session.aspx?ID=6b2a4b61-2f29-49cb-b428-72e3956501a7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier that you think.

```
private async Task<byte[]> StorageFileToByteArray(string fileName)  //filename = "no_capture_receipt.png"
{
    var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");

    var storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

    var buffer = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(storageFile);

    return buffer.ToArray();        
}
```

Don't forget to change the Copy to Output Directory of the image to `Copy if newer`!